# Avoiding for-loops in this Matlab matrix operation

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have a large 4 dimensional matrix, and I wish to 1) find the minimum of 2 of those dimensions (i.e. a 4000x4000 result) and then 2) count the number of elements in those last two dimensions that are less than (lets say) 5 times the minimum (i.e giving a result of 4000x4000). I'm a bit stumped as to how to do this without reverting to for loops

Some code might aid my description:

```
A      = rand([4000,4000,7,7]);
B(:,:) = min(A(:,:,1:7;1:7)); % this isn't quite right?
C      = size( A < 5*B ) % obviously totally wrong
```

any pointers would be great - many thanks!

Comment: if you write that for-loop, it would give us a better idea on what is it you are trying to do

Comment: You might consider using `prctile` rather than a fixed multiple of the minimum value.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood this correctly, the following should do the job:

```
mn = min(min(A,[],3),[],4);
num = sum(sum(bsxfun(@lt, A, 5*mn),3),4)
```

Comment: I think Amro's answer is exactly what I want, with the slight modification of changing 1 and 2 to 3 and 4, i.e. num = sum(sum(bsxfun(@lt, A, 5*mn),3),4)

Comment: @yoda, I don't think you are quite right here: A and mn have different dimensions, so A<5*mn already fails. Also, Amro's solution yields a 1x1x7x7 array, whereas nnz just yields one number (the sum over all 49 elements).

Comment: @trican: if this solution works for you, you can mark is as the accepted answer :-). Whether you wanted to have a 7x7 or 4000x4000 result wasn't really clear from your question, maybe you could clear that up for future readers of this thread ;-).

Comment: @trican: when trying to vectorize a piece of code, always start with the straightforward solution (the FOR-loop in this case), then incrementally start to optimize it. That way you get a baseline against which to compare both correctness and performance...

Comment: @Jonas: Ah, I see. I read OP's sentence "find the minimum of two of those dimensions" to mean he wanted the smallest dimension, in which case it'd be a scalar.

Answer (score -1):

First, it should be `rand([4000,4000,7,7])`

Second, to use min, you have to do something like `min(A, [], 1)` (replace 1 with the dimension)

Third, assuming you had `A` and `B`, you want `C = sum(sum(A < 5*B))`